Did Steve Gibson's Spinrite actually do anything useful by "refreshing" the disc's magnetic domains?
Spinrite saved my ass many times. It refreshed the low level disk format (sector definitions), something that DOS couldn't do.
But on 80s TV shows,  Steve said that it was necessary to rewrite the entire disk periodically, to "refresh" the fading magnetic domains. And it does appear that after time, ST220 disk sectors did used to just die.
But if that's true, how come it isn't necessary now?
Or was it ever?

Well it definitely won't be necessary on SSD drives.

I'd like to make a Steve Gibson fan club. He did some amazing stuff in security.

"Was it ever" is a retro question, but "why isn't it now" is not. @AlanB That's because it is likely that SSD controllers scan and refresh the fading memory cells themselves without user intervention like modern hard drived but the old hard drives didn't.

@Justme SSD wear occurs when information is written. That gives it a finite, predictable lifetime. That's how the controller knows when to retire a memory cell, and it's unrelated to the issue of magnetic domains in metals fading with time.

@JessFuckett Actually most of flash wearing is caused by erase process rather than write. You can always write individual bits low but erase happens in larger blocks. The charges do fade over years if left untouched, and flash wears out on read too - it's called "read disturb" and flash wear leveling algorithms need to handle that as well. So much for predictable life for SSDs. Yes, unrelated to magnetic media but somewhat similar.

For Gibson, the term 'spin doctor' is doubly appropriate.

@JessFuckett I've edited your comment, and removed some of the others. In future, feel free to flag for moderator attention when this happens. (We can also set up a private chat room if any time you want to discuss something.) (If you delete your last comment, you can flag this one as No Longer Needed. Otherwise, they'll probably be deleted in a few days.)

Thank you. When it becomes about me instead of the conversation, I leave the conversation.

Wild thing to say given that you made it about yourself to begin with.

@AdamHyland ? ? What the hell? I asked about MFM sector formatting.

I'm talking about comments you made in this thread which have since been deleted. Hope that helps!

Old-style hard disks and floppy drives were formatted by using the "ordinary" write process to write synchronization and sector identification marks in a manner that was blind to whatever had been on the disk.  During normal operation, to write a sector, the drive will listen for the synchronization mark that's followed by an identifier for the proper sector.  It will then turn on the write head and blindly write a sector's worth of data.
Some utilities, of which I would expect SpinRite to be one, will read each track of the disk, reformat it, and then rewrite the track with the data it had just read.  This would probably not be needed unless one wanted to change the sector interleave after getting a faster computer, but hard drive sectors did sometimes fail; it's unclear to how often failure was caused by gradual degradation and to what extent it was primarily caused by areas of the disk whose coating wasn't quite as good as it should have been, or an inferior region of coating which allowed magnetic domains to spread unusually fast.  I would expect that on some, perhaps many, hard drives in the 1980s there would have been areas that would work more reliably if periodically refreshed, but there would also have been many hard drives that would not need such treatment.  Today a sensible attitude toward storage media would be to regard any media that can't reliably hold magnetic domains indefinitely as meriting immediate replacement with media that can, but technology was nowhere near as refined in the 1980s as it has become in the decades since.  Even if one replaced a hard drive that wasn't fully trustworthy, there would be practical no way of knowing whether the replacement would be any better.

Older drives might have had some drift in the exact position of a track, resulting in offsets over time that would make it harder to read the bits.  Newer drives use servo tracking to stick to the track precisely so drift doesn't happen.

@supercat So you're saying that the  low level format is a myth?

Low-level format was real. There are three things you need to do to a freshly-coated magnetic disk: (1) record track and sector markings, (2) check for sectors that cannot reliably be written and re-read, (3) write an empty file system.  In computer systems that don't confuse meanings, these are called formatting, bad-block check, and initialize, respectively.  Formatting on site was once needed because removable disk packs were not necessarily sold for a particular geometry. With fixed disks, and especially with integrated HDAs, 'low level' formatting can be done at factory.

Yeah, but it didn't used to be. I specifically mentioned ST220 and the RLL era.

@dave: For years, drives have often had tracking and synchronization data written at a physically depeer layer on the disk than user data, at lower density, in a way that allows it to be read independently of the user data.  Equipment to record these markings needed to be extremely precisely calibrated, but a drive which could quickly move the head in and out in small increments could get by with much sloppier tolerances, since a drive could move somewhere near where it needed to go, read where it was, adjust its posiition, read where it was, and maybe perform a third adjustment if needed.

@dave: The magnetic field produced by the drive head when writing is so finely concentrated that it won't be able to affect magnetic flux states deeper within the media, and the drive will by nature adjust its behavior to accommodate any manufacturing variations in the mechanism.  This approach reminds me a little bit of the way phosphor dots are put on a color CRT.  The inside surface is coated with a resist layer, the screen is fed a signal to draw one color (eg. red), the parts of the resist layer that were hit with the beam are chemically etched, and then red phosphor is applied...

...to the parts of the glass where the resist was removed.  The process can then be repeated for green and blue.  Even if the position of the shadow mask relative to the screen surface is only specified e.g. +/- 1mm, the phosphor dots will be perfectly aligned with the shadow mask, because their position will be adapted to match whatever the shadow mask position happens to be.

@supercat - 'for years' - but this is Retrocomputing SE, where the decades just melt away, and we can all still fit into our 28" waist Levi's 501s.

@supercat - but I'm not really getting your point. Is it that there was/is a disk type where the low-level formatting is baked into the disk at the factory? I readily bow to your knowledge, but I'm saying that before that there was on-site formatting of packs. Although now I'm doubting whether I personally ever did that.

@dave The last time I ever had/could deal with low-level formatting was in the ST-506 days with MFM and RLL. As soon as IDE came around, I don't think you could even do a true low-level format even if you wanted to.

@ErikF - for framing, I regard the ST-506 as occurring relatively recently in the timeframe of interest to SE:RC.

@dave: I don't know what details to storage technology occurred when, but hard drives evolved in such a way that tracking information needed to be written to platters before the platters were installed in drives, both because a drive whose disks didn't already contain such information would have no way of knowing where to move its heads, and also because the drive heads wouldn't be powerful enough to write such information even if they had some way of knowing where they were positioned.  There may have been some drive makers that included electronics that could...

...allow a drive to physically write its tracking information with the aid of input from a factory's optical measuring equipment, but at some point the technology advanced to the point where that would have ceased to be practical.
